# How do I create an OutputStream that writes to a FileChannel

Tags: java, file, outputstream, filechannel

I have a [`FileChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) object (which I need so I can apply a `FileLock` to the file), and I want to write to the file it references using a simple [`OututStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html). How do I create an `OutputStream` that writes to a `FileChannel`?

This should be in the Java API somewhere, but I can't find it. `FileChannel` does not have a suitable factory method. The [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) class does not have a suitable constructor. The [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class (of Java 7) has no suitable methods.

Comment: I am answering my own question [as is encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Answer (score 0):

The Java API provides suitable factory methods in the [`Channels`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html) class. The factory method [`newOutputStream(WritableByteChannel)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html#newOutputStream%28java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel%29) can create an `OutputStream` for a given `FileChannel`, as a `FileChannel` *implements* `WritableByteChannel`.